# error "unrecognized selector sent to instance" after custom segue to different storyboard from delegate method

Tags: ios, delegates, storyboard, segue

I'm new to iOS programming, and I'm working on a project using storyboards. I'm using custom segues to transition between storyboards, which works fine. I'm performing one of the segues manually after a user enters a number into a `UITextField` then hits 'Return'. I'm using the following delegate method of the UITextField to handle the 'Return':

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"@MyStoryboardName" sender:self];
    return YES;
}
```

This successfully segues to the new storyboard. My custom segue uses this central method for performing the actual segue:

```
- (void)perform
{
    UIViewController *source = (UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
    [source.navigationController pushViewController:self.destinationViewController
                                           animated:YES];
    [source presentViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:YES completion:];
}
```

Following the segue though, I get an error "unrecognized selector sent to instance". I think this has something to do with the delegate method trying to complete after I've moved to the ViewController in the new storyboard, when the delegate is now out of scope? Is this what's happening, and if so, how do I fix this? Here is the stack trace (the view controller containing the text field is TimeDelayViewController):

```
2015-10-07 11:27:06.739 MyApp[584:28455] -[TimeDelayViewController timeDelay:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ca80bb0
2015-10-07 11:27:06.804 MyApp[584:28455] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TimeDelayViewController timeDelay:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ca80bb0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01063a94 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0078be02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0106cde3 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00faae3d ___forwarding___ + 1037
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00faaa0e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x007a00b5 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    6   UIKit                               0x013f4c40 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 118
    7   UIKit                               0x013f4bbf -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
    8   UIKit                               0x0158a8fc -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 79
    9   UIKit                               0x0158ac7c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 408
    10  UIKit                               0x01ea6e48 -[UITextField _resignFirstResponder] + 324
    11  UIKit                               0x01632e2f -[UIResponder _finishResignFirstResponder] + 347
    12  UIKit                               0x01ea6c49 -[UITextField _finishResignFirstResponder] + 51
    13  UIKit                               0x01632eef -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 159
    14  UIKit                               0x01ea6ae6 -[UITextField resignFirstResponder] + 141
    15  UIKit                               0x014a2231 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _removeFirstResponderFromSubtree] + 211
    16  UIKit                               0x014a276f __UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 74
    17  UIKit                               0x014a2598 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 99
    18  UIKit                               0x01585de4 __71-[UIPresentationController _initViewHierarchyForPresentationSuperview:]_block_invoke596 + 996
    19  UIKit                               0x0157f64a -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 113
    20  UIKit                               0x01780040 -[_UICurrentContextPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 56
    21  UIKit                               0x015837fc __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 224
    22  UIKit                               0x01ed7a5b -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 118
    23  UIKit                               0x01f01c91 -[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator transitionViewDidComplete:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 74
    24  UIKit                               0x0157c29e -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 280
    25  UIKit                               0x0157bf8a -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 1550
    26  UIKit                               0x0157ebc5 -[UITransitionView _transitionDidStop:finished:] + 121
    27  UIKit                               0x014873c7 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 247
    28  UIKit                               0x014877bd -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 90
    29  QuartzCore                          0x061ebe97 _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 305
    30  libdispatch.dylib                   0x038379cd _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    31  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0381d018 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 910
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x00fb570e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x00f73454 __CFRunLoopRun + 2356
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x00f72866 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x00f7267b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    36  GraphicsServices                    0x03c37664 GSEventRunModal + 192
    37  GraphicsServices                    0x03c374a1 GSEventRun + 104
    38  UIKit                               0x013f2cc1 UIApplicationMain + 160
    39  MyApp                            0x00045d3a main + 138
    40  libdyld.dylib                       0x03861a21 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Can you please post the full stacktrace? It should specifically mention which unrecognized method you're trying to call.

Comment: Please provide more information like a stack trace and the line of code where the crash happens. May be the crash isn't related to your segue at all may be it's something in your `destinationViewController`'s early stages like in `init` or `viewDidLoad`? Also, why are you pushing and presenting the view controller at the same time? This could be the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the stack trace

Comment: According to apple docs the perform method is for doing custom animations in a segue. I don't think you should be overriding that method if you're just going to call pushViewController and/or presentViewController.

Comment: @Ahmed - the destinationViewController is working OK, and I also push and present the view controller in other instances, and this also works, so that's not what's causing the issue.

Comment: `[TimeDelayViewController timeDelay:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` tells you everything you need to know.  *TimeDelayViewController* does not have a method named *timeDelay:*.

Answer (score 0):

According to apple docs the perform method is used for doing custom animations in a segue.

`Subclasses override this method and use it to perform the animations from the views in sourceViewController to the views in destinationViewController.`

I don't think you should be overriding that method if you're just going to call pushViewController and/or presentViewController, instead you should set up which view controllers get pushed or presented in a storyboard.

But I think what could be your error is the fact that you call both - you're trying to present destinationViewController from both the source view controller and source's navigationViewController at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that I'd initially tried to create an action for my UITextField by control-clicking the text field and automatically creating an IBAction in my implementation file. I removed the IBAction method, in order to instead respond to a delegate method of the UITextField, however I didn't remove the identifier which I'd assigned to the UITextField, and the UITextField was still being looked up using this identifier ('timeDelay'). I removed the entry that had automatically been created under 'Sent events' for my UITextField as shown below, and this fixed the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

{

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @"MyStoryboardName"])

{

```
UIViewController *source = (UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
```

source=segue.destinationViewController;

```
[self presentViewController:source animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

}